# How to post feed on Walmart using api?

Tags: api, walmart-api

I am integrating walmart api with my website. Is anyone know how to submit feed on walmart using api? Is there any example available?

Comment: I wouldn't expect too much attention here, as there's no tag for wallmart-api.

Comment: i want to mark this as wallmart-api but it was not available in tag list so i have not added this tag.

Comment: I understand, I just wanted to suggest that it means that it's likely nobody here used it. You can try to tag it with the language you use.

Comment: Have u solved this issue or still looking for solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to

> developer.walmart.com

to get all the insights of API call and SDK for the signature part. 
The feed submit calls involves the following aspects
First you need to generate signature by URL(complete) , timestamp , consumerId , requestMethod .

Then a curl request need to be sent upon the v3/feeds endpoint with the following headers

```
 WM_SVC.NAME: Walmart Marketplace
 WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID: 2lmnWiWak7IUcBcnEczyTw==
 WM_SEC.TIMESTAMP: 1485896379543
 WM_SEC.AUTH_SIGNATURE: jKQlCI4JovTR1ReIVRtOchc3OE9tKbcm9LpCPdq7sekCDOGzhbQFlop/XFX5hZGHWWmaj/mngmr8wNiIiYh1hPS9eQYyi78bOBo3nC49aE2gwSup1fBqZ2M9xQIp+0iGu5J/cNHtX76d+wmOKynsp/W9OBwHcNtgFy3m10Q39DM=
 WM_CONSUMER.ID: yourValue
 Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
 Accept: application/xml
 WM_CONSUMER.CHANNEL.TYPE:  your consumer channel type id
```

You also would need to include the XML file containing the product create xml . This can be done via a CurlFile class if you are in a php environment.
The curl request will be a post request which will output you a feedId. Record it for response and you can see an item feed submitted on Walmart.

Apart from these there are many 3rd party plugins which can be used for your integration with Walmart.